How to show in postman collections run results summary the name of the folders next to the name of the requests
I have a set of healtcheck requests defined in postman. For every project I have a folder of calls which I would like to perform every day. After I run collection I am able to see the summary where I can see all the requests which were being run with their tests. But they are not divided by folders. Some of the requests have the same name like: "login". I would like to be able to understand which login "failed" and which not just by seeing the summary.  but I cannot distinguish if they have same names. I do not want to rename the requests in all my projects and contain redundant information of the containing folder name. How can I configure postman to show also the containg folder name of the request on the summary page?


There currently isn't a way to show that folder structure in the Collection Runner UI.
As your requests don't actually have any tests, if would be good to add those. With those in place, you could use pm.execution.location to see the location of the request and add this to the test name.
Given the same Collection and Folder structure, you would need to reference the information you want to show to adding the index.
pm.test(`${pm.execution.location[1]} - Status code is 200`, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});


This isn't an ideal solution but it could make the location visible in the Collection Runner results view.

in the real life example I have around 5 test cases, I did not include them for more clarity. Anyhow your solution is good enough for me, because if I see one of the "requests" is failing I can just click it and all tests will be visible with their names and I will be able to identify quickly which project it was.

I've raised the visibility of the folders in this scenario with the team to look at, it feels like these should be visible at the level. You can click into the requests and see that but it feels like an unnecessary step. Appreciate you raising this.

I have followed solution of @Danny and for every request I add something like:
pm.test(`${pm.execution.location[1]}`, function () { 
}); 

pm.test(` Status code is 200`, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

// all other tests ...

After I run all collection and I see one of the requests failing, I can just expand it and see the containing tests. The first test will just show the name of the containing folder. Like in the image below:

